# Remove items from Object using their Index using Lodash

Tags: node.js, lodash, javascript-objects

I have an object like this:

```
[
  [
    'gfhasd',
    '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '3000000000000000000',
    '0',
    '0x',
    component: 'rgr',
    module: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    unit: '5000000000000000000',
    positionState: '0',
    data: '0x'
  ],
  [
    'zaradf',
    '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '500000000',
    '0',
    '0x',
    component: 'xyx',
    module: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    unit: '500000000',
    positionState: '0',
    data: '0x'
  ]
]
```

I wish to remove for each item indexes 0,1,2,3,4 since they are duplicate.

I'm trying something like this with lodash but its not working:

```
const pos = _.remove(positions, (item) => item[i] == 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it using the following code:

```
positions.forEach((position) => {
    //removes duplicates for a clearer print
    const pos = _.omit(position, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
})
```